# Show files list in QTreeView as a tree

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qtreeview

Is there an easy way to make some QStringList of files displaying in QTreeView as a tree?
Of course we can split every path by "/" and do some stuff like appendRow in QStandardItemModel and take a result. But I think there must be a simplier way.
For example, we have list of files like this (QStringList):

```
"dir/subdir/file.dat",
"dir/app.exe",
"other_dir/file2.dat"
```

Result must be a QTreeView like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to make some QStringList of files displaying in
>   QTreeView as a tree?

if the data is implied to be `QStringList` than the suggestion is to convert it to [TreeItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html#treeitem-class-definition)-based data and use Qt documentation example ["Simple Tree Model Example"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html). You cannot avoid creating tree-like structure one way or another for that. Find that example with Qt Creator or in its directory and look for [TreeModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html#treemodel-class-definition) class definition/implementation.

If the data is not from QStringList or some other form of in-memory collection but from actual file system: of course it is very doable. All you need is QFileSystemModel and QTreeView. One of possible somewhat similar examples [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTreeView_QFileSystemModel_ModelView_MVC.php).

Create the minimum UI you need and use the model filter like that:

```
auto* dirModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
dirModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot |
                    QDir::Files | QDir::Dirs);
```

... or you may specify better filter yourself if needed.

Comment: Thank you, okay.. Well anyway i will have to make tree struct) Wanna learn your link and example

Comment: Files list is from zip file (QuaZip). So I am trying display them in tree view like explorer

Comment: Yes, you have a bit of data structure exercise with that.